# Redux Thunk action creator not dispatching fetching api

Tags: react-redux, redux-thunk

I have created a small react-redux application to fetch api data with redux-thunk middleware, for some reason, the action creator function that returns dispatch is not working.

**Action Creators:**

```
export const fetchUsers = () => {
  console.log('test 1');
  return dispatch => {
    console.log('test 2');
    dispatch(fetchUserRequest);
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => {
        const users = response.data;
        dispatch(fetchUserSuccess(users));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(errorMessage));
      });
  };
};
```

`console.log('test 1')` is working but `console.log('test 2')` is not working.
Here is [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-hooks-ykmnc) link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a a few things:
in userTypes you were missing there is no `_` when you create const types for example `export const FETCH_USER_REQUEST = "FETCH USER REQUEST";` should be `export const FETCH_USER_REQUEST = "FETCH_USER_REQUEST";` also in userActions import it from userTypes not userReducers it should be `import {
  FETCH_USER_REQUEST,
  FETCH_USER_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_USER_FAILURE
} from "./userTypes";`

I have also fixed your userContainer, codesandbax: [codesandbax](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-hooks-tctl3)

Comment: You made another change that in the UserContainer.js file.  I didn't notice it as you didn't mention in the comment.  Now it's working, thank you.